# how to read json array without keys in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

Sample JSON Data : [Complex Github API](https://api.github.com/users/jiveshrelhan/repos)

Snippet from above github api.
[image]

Now i want list of 'full_name','owner.login' using typescript.

Comment: Do you want this? `var myArray = []; var obj = null; for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){ obj = {full_name: jsonData[i].full_name, owner_login: jsonData[i].owner.login; myArray.push(obj); }`

Answer (score 0):

you may use map function on JSON array, like below.

```
   let jsonResult = 'result from api call';
   let result = jsonResult.map(res => {
     return {
       full_name : res.full_name,
       owner_login: res.owner.login
     }
   })
```

`result` will have the list.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: No ! Actually, I am getting few errors : full_name property doesn't exists for res:Respone